# how can I move selected DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html

I want to move any selected block (by click etc.) in html document.

If I set `position: absolute` property the element removes from the flow and layout changes.
I see here only one option to use `position: relative` but in that case it hard to move it to left, center and right.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="solutions.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-primary p-5 hero-header">
        <div class="row py-5">
            <div class="col-8 text-center">
                <h1 class="display-1 text-white py-5" id="te">Some text</h1>
                <button class="h4 text-white btn btn-warning">Home</button>
                <i class="far fa-circle text-white px-2"></i>
                <button class="h4 text-white btn btn-success">Example</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I want to change 'Home' button to align right

```
let leftOffset = Math.ceil(window.innerWidth - document.querySelector("body > div > div > div > button.h4.text-white.btn.btn-warning").getBoundingClientRect().width - document.querySelector("body > div > div > div > button.h4.text-white.btn.btn-warning").offsetLeft)

document.querySelector("body > div > div > div > button.h4.text-white.btn.btn-warning").style.position = "relative"
document.querySelector("body > div > div > div > button.h4.text-white.btn.btn-warning").style.left = leftOffset + "px"
```

but the button goes off screeen

so I can't understand why it doesn't work. if I want to center it or align to left seems there will be more code to do it. If only I could use position absolute (left:0, 50, 100) and don't change the flow

Comment: Could you show what your after, it's a little unclear what your asking.

Comment: Why do you use JavaScript for this? This seems to be doable in the CSS. Also recommend to write useful classes so the selectors don't rely on the exact HTML hierarchy. Like having `.hero-header .btn-home` for example is easier to understand.

Comment: I need something like drag n drop, first select an element and drag to left/center/right with relative position

Comment: I want to move it like
`var target = document.querySelector("elem");
var left = target.getBoundingClientRect().left;
target.style.left = -left + "px";`

but then I need to move it to the right edge and to the center and it doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

If you want to move blue button next to yellow button,best way is use **flex box** display
So you can move buttons into div and set div display to **flex** and you can manage the position of your elements in that div